# Snap Ins: How to get first name and last name values of chat box in JavaScript dynamically?

Tags: javascript, liveagent

How to get the details entered in the chat box in javascript?
[image]

In javaScript, I am trying to create Account but need the name entered in the chat box.
As of now, I am hardcoding to create account.

```
 embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatFormDetails = [{
                    "label": "Name",
                    "value": "Last Name",
                    "transcriptFields": [],
                    "displayToAgent": true
                }];
embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
                    "entityName": "Account",
                    "showOnCreate": true,
                    "saveToTranscript": "AccountId",
                    "entityFieldMaps": [{
                        "isExactMatch": true,
                        "fieldName": "Name",
                        "doCreate": true,
                        "doFind": true,
                        "label": "Name"
                    }]
                }];
```

Is there any way to create Person Accounts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to create a custom pre-chat page if you haven't done so. Information and code examples can be found here: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/snapins_web_dev_guide.pdf

Once you have the pre-chat page you will be able to get the data entered by doing the following:

```
var prechatFieldComponents = component.find("prechatField");

var apiNamesMap = helper.createAPINamesMap(component.find("prechatAPI").getPrechatFields());

var fields = helper.createFieldsArray(apiNamesMap, prechatFieldComponents);
```

`fields` will be an array with all of the fields the user input values into.

Then you can access the field values by doing something like `var currentValue = fields[0].value`